# make a Shift in for each cl in Range VBA

Tags: excel, for-loop, each, offset, vba

I have a loop like this but meanwhile I need to scape some of the cells.

```
For Each qcell In oNOcells

' here I would like to scape some of the cells under specific condition,

Next qcell
```

how can I make offset to the qcell and ask it to go for 3 cells after the qcell?

Comment: So, as you loop through the cells, if a cell meets a given condition, you want to skip two cells and move to the third cell after the cell that met the condition?

Answer (score 0):

**REVISED CODE**

The following sub steps through a range of cells. If the value in the current cell meets a specified condition, the code skips that cell and a specified number of additional cells; otherwise, it does something at the current cell.

For purposes of example, the range in the code is set at A1:A20, and the specified condition is that a cell contains the value 2.

Note that the code does not skip ahead every time the specified condition would be met in the range, since those cells that are among the skipped cells do not trigger another skip ahead. For cells that do not meet the condition and are not skipped, the sub prints out a message to the Immediate window.

To adjust the number of cells that are skipped, adjust the value of the variable num_of_cells_to_skip.

```
Sub skip_ahead()
    Dim oNoCells As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim skip_forward As Long
    Set oNoCells = Range("A1:A20")
    i = 1
    count = oNoCells.Rows.count
    num_of_cells_to_skip = 2
    Do While i <= count
        If oNoCells.cells(i, 1).Value = 2 Then
            i = i + num_of_cells_to_skip + 1
        Else
            Debug.Print "do something at cell " & oNoCells.cells(i, 1).Address
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I faced the problem exactly t the Next qcell. this commant will cause to go for the exactly next qcell, but what if  I needed to instead of next qcell I want to jump to the second or third qcell at instead of the next qcell.

Comment: Yes, the routine goes to the next qcell, but doesn't do anything, just passes to the one after that. To do what you want, it's better to use Do While / Loop; that way you can control the interval of the jump. See my revised code above, which skips a specified number of cells in one iteration of the loop, as you are looking for.